# SQL table schema missing critical data - not able to answer question

Tags: sql, database-design, schema

Based on the below schemas of these 4 tables, is there any way to find the top active studies by total revenue spent since the start of study for a particular advertiser?

From my understanding of the schemas, there is no way to attribute revenue from a particular date to any one study (from the schema, you can look at revenue by date for a specific advertiser_id and advertiser_name, but then that revenue cannot be reconciled with a specific study_id, study_name, or study_type).  The problem is, that studies (from what I've seen in the data) can be run concurrently, like study 1 and study 2 for advertiser A can both be active/running on 03-28-2020, making it impossible to reconcile what revenue earned on 3-28-2020 is attributed to study 1 and what is study 2.

Am I missing something?  And if the schemas provided currently don't support an answer to this question, how could I attribute revenue by date (if the date falls between the start_date and end_date of a particular study_id/study_name) to any study_id/study_name active on that date?  Using a case when statement maybe?  Finally, how can I define 'active' with a where clause, by making the end_date >= today's date?

Thanks!

Comment: You edited out your image. But please don't put an image back in; use text. Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted.

Comment: Please give all constraints that hold (whether declarable in SQL or not). When constraints hold, some expressions always return the same result as other expressions that wouldn't otherwise. If a DB question can be expressed without knowing constraints, constraints just give more expression options. But if a question can't be expressed or would be sometimes be undefined, under constraints it might become equivalent to a previously expressible question. So maybe your question can't be expressed/asked/answered when your constraints don't hold but can be when they do.

Comment: Please ask 1 question per post. If you get stuck writing a query, give a [mre] & show what relevant queries you can write & explain about the 1st subexpression that doesn't return what you expect. [ask] [help]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you already figured out, if an advertizer has more than one study at the same time, it is not possible to answer your question.